# Arrays inside a Arraylist

Tags: arrays, arraylist

i need to build up an `ArrayList` with `Integer` in new `Array`s in it. How can I setup this and add items?

```
private final ArrayList<Integer>[] test;

test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This won't work.

Thank you!

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean by - ArrayList with Integer in new Arrays in it ??

Comment: the elements of `test` Arraylist are again Arrays of Integer..is that what you are saying?

Comment: i want to setup an arraylist and the objects in the arraylist are arrays of with Integer. I don´t know how to set up this Arraylist. a normal ArrayList isnt a Problem. So how can i initialize the ArrayList and then add Integer Arrays ?

Comment: so basically List with arrays as elements..check my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to create a 2-dimansional integer array.

I assume you have a special use case in which you need a primitive array ob ArrayList-Objects.

Anyways you can create such a thing like any other primitive array
like

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] test = new ArrayList[2];
```

and access/set it by index..

```
test[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You also can fill the array on init...

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] test = new ArrayList[] {
        new ArrayList<Integer>(),
        new ArrayList<Integer>(),
        new ArrayList<Integer>()
};
```

Answer (score 2):

An array is an `Object`, and you can make lists of any object type - so you can make a `List` of arrays without doing anything special:

```
// Declare it and initialise as an empty list
List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

// Add an item -- it's a new array
list.add(new Integer[5]);

// Access an item -- it's an array
Integer[] array = list.get(0);
Integer x = array[0];
```

I see few reasons to use arrays of `Integer` for most situations, however. An array of `int` is also an `Object` so you can use that just as well.

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new int[5]);
```

One of the most common reasons for using the object `Integer` rather than the primitive `int` is that you can't have `List`s of primitives. But you *can* have arrays of primitives, so if you're happy with the lesser expressive power of the array, by all means populate it with primitives.

Ask yourself why you want a `List` of arrays rather than a `List` of `List`s, an array of arrays or an array of `List`s, however.

---

Your question asks for "Arrays inside an ArrayList".

`List<Integer[]>` is a list of arrays (because, inside the `<>`, is `Integer[]`).

`List<Integer>[]` is an array of lists -- "ArrayLists inside an array" --  because the `[]` comes after the `List<>` declaration.

You can initialise your array of lists just like any other array, with `new Type[length]`:

```
 // Declare it
 List<Integer>[] array = new List<Integer>[5]; 

 // Put something into an array element
 array[3] = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 // Access an element -- it's a List
 List<Integer> list = array[3];
 Integer x = list.get(0);
```

Comment: hi, i'm not allowed to change this code: private final ArrayList<Integer>[] test; --> so can u initalize this code? It starts with an ArrayList and the [] are outside the diamond operator. In your Code the [] are in the diamond operator.

Comment: valenth - `ArrayList<Integer>[]` is an array of lists, not a list of arrays. Will add something to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we want [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) inside [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) then -

```
class Test {

  private final List<int[]> myList;

  public Test() {
      myList = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void add(int[] myArray) {
     myList.add(myArray);
  }  
}
```

***You are always allowed to initialize a final variable. The compiler makes sure that you can do it only once.***

Comment: it is not allowed to change private "final ArrayList<Integer>[] test;", so i have to build it up with these specifications. Just need to know how to initialize these. thank you

Comment: check the modified answer once..also i guess you should read about final keyword in java.

Comment: yeah this works, but how i said, i do not have to change this: "private final ArrayList<Integer>[] test; -> So can you initialize this code too? If i change your code to: private final List<int>[] myList, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: you have to initialize it somewhere mate!! if not in the constructor then do it where its declared..`private final List<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();` and then you can remove the initialization in constructor..

Comment: @valenth you can't have a `List<int>` because `int` is a primitive. And therefore you can't have an array of `List<int>` either. This is one reason for the existence of `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

u can use like this for do this

```
private ArrayList<Integer>[] test ;

private void test(int n){
    test=new ArrayList[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         test[i]=new ArrayList<Integer>();

         test[i].add(100);
         test[i].add(10);
         test[i].add(10000);
         test[i].add(1);
         ....
    }
}
```